# Disable hyphenation for proper nouns in Romanian language

Tags: hyphenation, hyphenat

**I'm not sure that my question is related to `hyphenat package` or to [Romanian hyphen pattern](https://github.com/hyphenation/tex-hyphen/blob/master/hyph-utf8/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-ro.tex) that are loaded in LaTeX.**

According to Romanian grammar definition:

> Proper nouns name objects of the same kind to distinguish them from others and are written in capital letters, regardless of the place they occupy in the sentence.

So I want in my thesis to globally disable hyphenation for proper nouns.
There is a problem involved here: detection of proper noun at the beginning of a sentence

> 1. Bucharest is the capital of Romania.

and

> 2. According to John Doe we don't get the bonus.

In 1st sentence words `Bucharest` & Romania `must not` be hyphenate `BUT` in 2nd sentence let `According` to be hyphenate but `NOT` John OR Doe.

Comment: I can't see how you get from the definition that proper names shouldn't be hyphenated. Anyway, it's possible to avoid hyphenation for words starting with a capital letter, but TeX is not able to distinguish the *meaning* of a word.

Comment: In Romanian language proper names are not allowed to be hyphenate because can create strange sentences: They are not separated at the end of the row, but are passed in full on the following row:
   - abbreviations written bound (UNESCO, AIDS) or separated by blanks (S N C F R), by dots (a.c.) or by hyphen (lt.-maj., N-V);
   - proper names of persons: Popescu, Abil el-Kader not: Po-pescu / Popes-cu; Abd el-ZKader);
   - ordinal numerals written with numbers and letters: V-lea, 5- «(not: V- / lea, 5- / a);

Comment: I know that this is not what you seek, but a way to avoid hyphenation is to include your word in a `\makebox{<your word>}`. It could be very annoying to search and replace every instance of proper names in your thesis, but anyway...